# violated - parent key not found error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following error appearing:

```
INSERT INTO GroupMembers VALUES ('Goldfrat', 'Simon Palm')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SHAHA1.IAM_IS_GROUP_FK) violated - parent key 
not found
```

The constraint in the `GroupMembers` table is:

```
CONSTRAINT  iam_is_group_fk FOREIGN KEY(is_group) REFERENCES Members(group_name)
```

The Members Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Members (
  group_name  VARCHAR2(40),
  CONSTRAINT  g_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(group_name),
  CONSTRAINT  m_group_name_fk FOREIGN KEY(group_name) REFERENCES Artist(artistic_name));
```

All of the tables are created fine until it comes to creating the `GroupMembers` table. Anyone have any ideas? I've been scratching for quite a while.

Comment: I'm scratching for the error,too.
I've disabled the foreign constraint and did some insert and delete actions.
After I updated, I could not enable this foreign constraint.
It said ORA-02298: cannot validate (PRODUSR.SYS_C0037867) - parent keys not found.
But I checked many times and still cannot find out any records not in parent table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that

`CONSTRAINT  iam_is_group_fk FOREIGN KEY(is_group) REFERENCES Members(group_name); references the table Members on the group_name field.`

This means that the field `is_group` on the table `GroupMembers` must have an identical value on the table `Members` and `group_name` field.

In my opinion, this is bad practice.
First of all, you should have a primary key field on the table `GroupMembers`. You should not store the names of the group members in the table `GroupMembers`, but their corresponding id from the table Members.

Also, the table Members should look something like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE Members (
    member_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
    member_name  VARCHAR2(40),
    CONSTRAINT  g_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(member_id),
    CONSTRAINT  m_group_name_fk FOREIGN KEY(group_name) REFERENCES Artist(artistic_name));
```

Then on the table `GroupMembers`, I suppose you want to associate some members to their set of groups and back, so you should do something like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE GroupMembers (
        member_id   NUMBER,
        group_id    NUMBER
    )
    CONSTRAINT  iam_is_member_fk FOREIGN KEY(member_id) REFERENCES Members(member_id);
    CONSTRAINT  iam_is_member_fk FOREIGN KEY(group_id) REFERENCES Groups(group_id);
```

Supposing that you have a table `Groups` containing all the group details, with the `primary key` stored as `number` , and name `group_id`.

Always remember that each table must have a `primary key`. It is good practice for this key to be a number.

So by having `member_id` in `Members`, `group_id` in `Groups`, you can create a **many-to-many relationship** in `GroupMembers`. Also, put a unique index on this table so you don't have duplicates ( the same member associated with the same id several times ).

Look at this example linking users to roles. It is the same case:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

error is
you have to use same column name which is defined in reference table

i.e

`CONSTRAINT  m_group_name_fk FOREIGN KEY(group_name) REFERENCES Artist(group_name)`

That `group_name` should be define as `primary key` in `Artist` Table.

Comment: No, you don't, have a look at the accepted answer. 
Moreover, please use the code block in your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Order in which you are insert is the reason for the error.

`Members(group_name)` does not contain `Goldfrat`. If this is not true then it's not there in the table `Artists`.

Comment: I'm inserting that line after i insert everything else