# ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C0011205) violated - parent key not found

Tags: database

SQL> select * from pass;

```
PNR_NO  TICKET_NO NAME       PP_NO
```

---

```
     0       1234 mahes        369
  9879      12345 rayud        368
```

SQL> select * from tic;

TICKET_NO NAME              AGE GENDE

---

```
  1234 mahesh             20 male
 12345 rayudu             20 male
123456 daa                22 male
  2580 javi               45 M
  2456 jani               25 F

SQL> insert into pass values(2456,123456,'daa',452);
insert into pass values(2456,123456,'daa',452)
```

- 

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C0011205) violated - parent key not
found
```

Comment: Please provide table constraints definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [violated - parent key not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518246/violated-parent-key-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

While inserting do enter the column name. Hope this will work for you

```
insert into pass(PNR_NO ,TICKET_NO ,NAME,PP_NO) values(2456,123456,'daa',452);
```